# How to get Internet Explorer AutoFill Data?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

I was looking for some information in a database and made some queries.

Internet explorer 11 obviously stores my queries in some (registry?) file. I hope it is not encrypted.

For some reason I'd like to get the queries for external use. How can I do it?

Comment: not registry. And: I hope it's encrypted. And: what do you mean by queries? There's a lot of different things browsers store.

Comment: @MarcusMüllerꕺꕺ For example, I've typed some words in a google search field and now I want to document all the queries I've made.

Comment: this is probably not IE but google. IE does have autofill. I'm pretty sure it doesn't look like the database you expect.